# Wrong result using hql 'or'

Tags: hibernate, hql

I don't know what am I missing here. I'm trying to run a query as follow:

```
String query = "select e from Event e where (eventType.operation='LIKE' and relatedPost.creatorPerson.personId=:person1Id)"
                + " or (eventEntity.relatedEntity='PERSON' and eventType.operation='FOLLOW' and relatedPerson.personId=:personId)"
                + " order by creationDate desc";
beginTx();
Query q = session.createQuery(query);
q.setInteger("personId", id1);
q.setInteger("personId1", id2);
List<Event> events = q.list();
commitTx();
```

When I query each side of 'or' separately, I get correct results. but when running whole above query, I just get result of left side of 'or'.

Any helps please?

Comment: I guess `relatedPost.creatorPerson` will result in an inner join (actually even two) and therefor you will not get any results for the right part of the `or` when `relatedPost` or `relatedPost.creatorPerson` is null.

Comment: Actually I'm new to hql and didn't get what to do to fix it. But when I switch two sides of the 'or'  I still get results of left side.

Comment: If I remember right you have to explicitly specify a left join: `select e from Event e left join e.relatedPost as rp left join rp.creatorPerson as cp where (eventType.operation='LIKE' and cp.personId=:person1Id) or (eventEntity.relatedEntity='PERSON' and eventType.operation='FOLLOW' and relatedPerson.personId=:personId) order by creationDate desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I'm quite sure about my comments...

The problem is that `relatedPost.creatorPerson` will result in an inner join (actually even two) and therefor you will not get any results for the right part of the `or` when `relatedPost` or `relatedPost.creatorPerson` is `null`. You should get a result if you explicitly specify some left joins:

```
select e from Event e 
left join e.relatedPost as rp 
left join rp.creatorPerson as cp
where (eventType.operation='LIKE' and cp.personId=:person1Id) 
or (eventEntity.relatedEntity='PERSON' and eventType.operation='FOLLOW' and relatedPerson.personId=:personId) order by creationDate desc
```